# Why would I use typecasting in Swift?

Tags: swift, casting, typecast-operator

Why would i be using typecasting in Swift?

I'm learning the language and I came across the subject of typecasting (e.g. down and upcasting etc.), but in my eyes it seems like a bit of a hassle. Why would i typecast an object? When would this be useful in real life applications or code?
I've looked on the internet for a bit but I can not seem to find a unambiguous answer. I'm really stuck with this so some help would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_casting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key case here is downcasting. You would do that because *you* might know what type an object really is, but the *compiler* doesn't know, so it won't let you send that type's messages to that object.

Example:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let dest = segue.destination as? FlipsideViewController {
        dest.delegate = self
    }
}
```

`segue.destination` is typed as UIViewController; that is just a fact, and is not up to you, because a segue's destination needs to be able to be *any* kind of UIViewController.

Only *you* know that *this* view controller is actually a FlipsideViewController. If you don't tell the compiler that, you can't set its `delegate` property (a plain vanilla UIViewController has no `delegate` property).

So to sum up: the common downcasting situation is when a type needs to be declared as the superclass because *any* subclass needs to be acceptable, but then in a particular instance you know *what* subclass it is so you need to cast down to that.

Comment: but why would you not just declare it as a specific type?

Comment: The declaration might not be up to you. I'll add an example.

Comment: because of inheritance and trying to not repeat yourself. If you have a, e.g, `DataSource` that is core and then you create specific `MyTopicDataSource: DataSource`, then you may want to see if you are handling with `MyTopicDataSource` out of 10 or 20 you have to make some special decisions without having to write a complete new VC for one different behaviour.

Comment: i went throught the link you just gave me but it seems that makes it even more complicated for me. The whole function in which it takes an argument of type Dog, why not take an argument of type NoisyDog?

Comment: In the artificial example I gave you, we want `func tellToHush(_ d:Dog)` to accept _any_ Dog. So `d` is declared as Dog. But inside `tellToHush`, we want to do something special just in case `d` is _really_ a NoisyDog as well.

Comment: But that is artificial; the example I gave you in the answer above is very real.

Comment: so all in all typecasting is used so an object has a specific type in a class hierarchy to inherit the properties of the super class when needed?

Comment: I still find it kind of hard to comprehend, sorry for that

Comment: "so all in all typecasting is used so an object has a specific type in a class hierarchy to inherit the properties of the super class when needed?" Not _all_ typecasting. There is also just plain sideways casting, i.e. bridging. Read on in the section I pointed you to in my book. But that is what _down_ casting is, yes; otherwise there would be no "down". It is about type and subtype (e.g. superclass and subclass).

Answer (score 0):

Typecasting is used when you are not sure about the type of any variable or class.
Suppose a variable value is setting from the server response . And it can be of multiple object type like String , Int , Double. Then you need typecasting to know what exactly type you are looking for.